# Capture traffic between amazon s3 and android application

Tags: android, xamarin, amazon-s3, fiddler

I need to see and probably edit amazon s3 responces to multipart upload. I use Fiddler, but it doesn't see any traffic between application and device. However, Fiddler is able to capture traffic between PC browser (I use Opera) and amazon s3. Both PC and android device are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
Is it possible to do so?